# Fill HTML input field using Swift Webkit doesn't work

Tags: html, swift, forms, webkit, getelementbyid

I am building an iOS app as a new interface to our club website.

Since I'm fairly new to this I watched several videos and looked on various websites for help. However, populating username, and password still does not happen:
Clicking the Sign In button works.

This is the login website: https://leamingtonst.aspsystems.co.uk/bookitasp/bookitasp.dll/cookielog

This is my code so far:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

let webView = WKWebView()

var counter = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
                           
    let url = URL(string: "https://leamingtons.aspsystems.co.uk/bookitasp/bookitasp.dll/cookielog")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 350, width: 300, height: 400)
    webView.load(request)
    view.addSubview(webView)
    
    }
    
@IBAction func submitTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    print("Value: \(usernameTextField.text!)")
    print("Value: \(passwordTextField.text!)")
    
        switch counter {
        case 0:
        // Populate username and password
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClass('username').value = '\(usernameTextField.text!)';", completionHandler: { (res, error) -> Void in
            if res != nil {
                print(res!)
                } })
            
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClass('password').value = '\(passwordTextField.text!)';", completionHandler: { (res, error) -> Void in
            if res != nil {
                print(res!)
                } })

            webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('pabutton').click();", completionHandler: nil)
                          
        
        case 1: break
        case 2: break
        case 3: break
        case 4: break
        case 5: break
        default: break
        }
            counter += 1
    }      
 }
```

I am grateful for any suggestions or ideas.

Comment: What do you mean by "populating username and password still does not happen" ?

Comment: I have two separate text boxes in my iOS app for username and password. I want to be able to login on the website with those two instances, hence transfer them to the input text fields on the website. Is this how it should work? I watched a youtube video which showed this approach.